# How can we assign points to users in the site?

Tags: users

I want to give points to users in the site, like if a user creates an account then he should be awarded some points even if I want to award points for the  activities like if user visits a page, if a user posts a comment etc.

Answer (score 3):

There is a module for that, [userpoints](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints)

Also using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to assign them for certain actions is common with that module.